# how to enable drag and drop tables from EDM datasource?

Tags: winforms, ado.net-entity-data-model

I created a c# winform project.  I added Entity Data Model.  I set the data model property "code generation" to default.  The list of tables showed up in the datasource window, but when I try to drag and drop a table on the designer window of the form, it does not work.
I'm frustrated.  I do not know what I'm missing.  Please help!!!

Comment: What does 'it does not work' mean?

Comment: What I meant is that I can't drag it

Comment: I was able to figure it out.

Comment: couldn't you delete the question, since this isn't going to be answered, or give the answer yourself..

Comment: yes, after adding EDM, go to Datasource to add new datasource, then select Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  here...

The only thing that was missing from was I was doing is that I needed to go the Datasource window, then right click to select to add new datasource, then from this window select 
**object**.  Then you select the newly added EDM.  After that you should be able to drag and drop table objects to your form.  Make sure that the data model property "code generation strategy" is set to default.